# "Make install" vs "Make install clean"?

Tags: linux, unix, installation, makefile

In *nix, when I compile software, when should I do:

```
# make install
```

vs

```
# make install clean
```

?

Answer (score 3):

When you call `make` with arguments, you are giving it a list of *targets*.

There is some discussion of this in the [Upgrading Ports section of the FreeBSD Handbook](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/ports-using.html#PORTS-UPGRADING) where it says:

```
Unlike the usual make install clean command, it will upgrade all
the dependencies prior to building and installing the selected
port.

[...]

Note: You can save two extra steps by just running make install
clean instead of make, make install and make clean as three
separate steps.
```

Also, as a side note: Don't build your package as root unless you really need to. In general you should work in an unprivileged account and then as a final step you can do `sudo make install` if you have to. It would be better, though, to add the unprivileged user to a group with write-access to the install directories, or even better to install it into a non-system area (for example, with `./configure` you can use `--prefix=`) since most systems, whether Linux or BSD, usually have packages and a packaging system that is used to install software.

Comment: So "make install clean" is equivalent to executing 3 separate commands: make, make install, make clean?

Comment: @Hank8 and @yi_H actually it is **one** command with **two** targets that, in a sense, **is** equivalent to executing the three separate commands. Implicit in the `make` command by itself is a call to `make all` which, presumably but not necessarily, `make install` has dependencies that would make it equivalent.

Comment: @aculich: nope, plain `make` means to execute the default command (configurable in the Makefile). that doesn't get executed if you specify commands (unless it is a dependency to one of the specified commands).

Comment: @yi_H you are right that it means to execute the default command which corresponds to the first target encountered in the makefile. The convention in GNU and many other programs is to make `all:` the first target so that it is the default. And again, by convention, `make install` generally (but not necessarily) has the dependencies required to invoke the *equivalent* of `make all`.